# How to modify fuelux repeater binding to secondary js object

Tags: javascript, fuelux

I need to modify the fuelux repeater grid.  I need to bind to the child object and display additional icons and messages.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following function inside the initialization method for the list row rendered method:
list_rowRendered: CustomRowRenderer

```js
function CustomRowRenderer(helpers, callback) {
        // let's get the id and add it to the "tr" DOM element
        var item = helpers.item;
        var rowData = helpers.rowData;
        debugger; 

        var customMarkup = "<tr><td colspan='4'><div style='float:left;'>";
        customMarkup += "<div class='btn-group'>"
        customMarkup += "<a class='btn btn-xs btn-primary' href='/Lead/ConvertToOpportunity/" + rowData.id + "'><i class='material-icons'>swap_horiz</i> Convert To Opportunity</a>";
        customMarkup += "<a class='btn btn-xs' href='/Lead/ScheduleCall/" + rowData.id + "'><i class='material-icons'>schedule</i> Schedule Call</a>";  
        customMarkup += "<a class='btn btn-xs' href='/Lead/ScheduleCall/" + rowData.id + "'><i class='material-icons'>question_answer</i> Add Note</a>"; 
        customMarkup += "</td></tr>";
        item.after(customMarkup);

        callback();
    }
```